# Are synonymous `typedef`s in C interchangable?

Tags: c, visual-studio, clang, typedef

The declaration `qboolean SNDDMA_InitDirect (void);` appears in ['WinQuake/snd_win.c' on line 69](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/master/WinQuake/snd_win.c#L69). However, the [function's definition (appearing on line 183 of the same file](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/master/WinQuake/snd_win.c#L183) is written as:

```
sndinitstat SNDDMA_InitDirect (void)
{
    /* Actual implementation is unimportant in this discussion. */
}
```

Both `qboolean`, and `sndinitstat` are `typedef`s of enumerations: `sndinitstat` on [line 33 of 'WinQuake/snd_win.c'](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/master/WinQuake/snd_win.c#L33),

```
typedef enum {SIS_SUCCESS, SIS_FAILURE, SIS_NOTAVAIL} sndinitstat;
```

and `qboolean` in ['WinQuake/common.h' (line 30)](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/master/WinQuake/common.h#L30)

```
typedef enum {false, true} qboolean;
```

These are **different enumerations**.

I have been compiling this source with both Visual Studio 2015's built in compiler -- *cl.exe* -- and Clang v3.7.1 via the LLVM plugin for Visual Studio. Clang states that this difference in declaration/definition is an error. Visual Studio compiles this okay. **Who is correct?**

Now, to quote *C: A Reference Manual (Fourth Edition)*:

- Section **5.5 Enumerated Types** (page 127)

  > The enumeration constants are specified when the type is defined and have the type `int`.
- Section **5.10 Typedef Names** (page 149)

  > Declarations with the `typedef` storage specifier do not introduce new types; the names are considered synonymous for types that could be specified in other ways.

These two paragraphs read to me as if Clang's error is, while helpful, incorrect according to the standard. But I know Microsoft don't have the greatest reputation with correctly compiling C.

Comment: Are they `typedef`s for the same list of enumerations? Or to put it another way, you should add the definitions of `qboolean` and `sndinitstat` to the question.

Comment: Inconsistencies of C standard interpretations are not uncommon between compilers.  In my compiler, even when set to its most strict settings does not recognize different alias's for the same type as an error.  In my opinion, at the most any compiler should do is flag it as a warning, but not an error.

Comment: I found `typedef enum {SIS_SUCCESS, SIS_FAILURE, SIS_NOTAVAIL} sndinitstat;` in the link.  Do you have access to the typedef for `qboolean`?  It is referenced in the link, but its definition is probably in one of the header files.

Comment: @user3386109 - If the enums for the two alias name were the same, then a _redeclaration_ compiler error would be required.  The enums have to be completely different.

Comment: @ryyker So you're saying I can't do `enum x {...}; typedef enum x y; typedef enum x z;` All I'm saying is that the OP needs to post the code that causes the error, otherwise the question is useless.

Comment: @user3386109 - no,  I was thinking of two separate enum definitions, having identical contents, but with different name. (that would never work of course.)   The way you have it is fine.

Comment: I thought I implied these were different enumerations. However I have updated the question with actual definitions and where to find these in the project source.

Comment: Because Visual Studio treats anonymous enums as type `int`. So the typedefs are equivalent to `typedef int qboolean` and `typedef int sndinitstat`. Hence, Visual Studio thinks `qboolean` and `sndinitstat` are the same type. Common sense (and clang) says that's spectacularly wrong. How a language lawyer would would interpret the spec is debatable, but somewhat pointless. If the correct interpretation of the spec says that Visual Studio is correct, then that just means that the spec is spectacularly wrong.

Comment: The sentence you quote from section 5.5 of _C: A Reference Manual (Fourth Edition)_ is 6.7.2.2/3 of the C11 standard: "The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int..." But that's not talking about the enumeration types themselves; it is talking about the *members* of the enumeration types. In `enum Vague {MAYBE, MAYBE_NOT};` `MAYBE` and `MAYBE_NOT` are constants of type `int`, but it is quite possible that `enum Vague x` is compatible with `char` and occupies just one byte (even when `int` is four bytes).

Comment: "*The enumeration constants are specified when the type is defined and have the type `int`.*" -- That's true, but not relevant to the question. Enumeration constants are always of type `int`. The enumeration *type* is not (though it may or may not be compatible with `int`). So given `enum foo { zero, one }; enum foo obj;` the constants `zero` and `one` are of type `int`, but `obj` is of type `enum foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If enum types hidden behind typedef names `qboolean` and `sndinitstat` are *compatible*, then the code is OK. If they are *not compatible*, then the code is erroneous. (See [**6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type**](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.2.7.html)).

If both function declarations are present in the same translation unit then the return type compatibility requirement is becomes more strict to the point where the types have to be *identical*.

In your case, two tagless enum types are used to define these `typedef` names. The enum declarations are sufficiently different to make them *incompatible*. That means that the code in question does indeed contain an error and Clang is right to complain. Visual Studio misses this error.

<strike>Note though that Clang (as well as GCC) take it to another extremity - they report an error even when there's none. For example, these declarations</strike>

```
enum { A1, A2, A3 } foo();
enum { B1, B2, B3 } foo();
```

result in the same error in Clang and GCC, even though the code is valid. In this example the tagless enum types are *compatible*, which is sufficient to justify the change in the return type of `foo` between declarations.

Comment: While the other answer is technically correct, your answer provides a more indepth response with reading materials so I'm marking this as the accepted answer. Thank-you!

Comment: I'm not convinced that those types are compatible. The standard says (emphasis added) "Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types ***declared in separate translation units*** are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements:". Clang and GCC seem to be taking the standard at its word.

Comment: @rici: You are right. The "...declared in separate translation units..." part is indeed very important. I missed it.

Comment: @Alex Melbourne: My answer is not entirely accurate. In your case the conflict happens when two declarations meet in the same translation unit. In such cases in order to be *compatible* the return types have to be *identical*.

Answer (score 3):

They refer to different enumerations:

```
typedef enum {false, true}  qboolean;
typedef enum {SIS_SUCCESS, SIS_FAILURE, SIS_NOTAVAIL} sndinitstat;
```

According to 6.2.5:16,

> Each distinct enumeration constitutes a different enumerated type.

So Clang is certainly correct.